# Error while running project in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am new to DNN. I have a project created in DNN, when i tried to run it, it shows me the below error.
[image: Error Message coming while running the project]. please help me how can i resolve this error and make my project in running mode.

Comment: Did you try what was mentioned in the message?

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual studio With Administration privilege.

Without Administration privilege you can't debug Visual Studio for the application hosted in IIS. VS can only apply Debug mode on Admin privilege.

**Edit:**

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj662724.aspx

Comment: are you sure about this?

Comment: @Thamotharan i am using the admin ... but it showing the same error

Comment: @Ram then there will be some other problem. Post your entire code.

Comment: @Ram Post your Web.config  alone.